# Rails 4.0 Nested forms / data not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following code trying to create a new User with an associated new Shop resource. However, while the user data is saved correctly, no record for the shop is created. What is wrong?

Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.shops.build
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Signed up successfully."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Signup failed!"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,
                                   shop_attributes: [:name])
    end
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shops
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shops
end
```

Shop model:

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

    <%= f.fields_for :shop do |shop| %>
      <%= shop.label :name %>
      <%= shop.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Create my account" %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your singular/plural wording (shop_attributes, f.fields_for :shop):

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,
                               shops_attributes: [:name])
end
```

and:

```
<%= f.fields_for :shops do |shop| %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! With 'build' I get and "undefined method `build' for #<Class:0x007f9ac4deff60>" error :-(

Comment: Ok, I have edited my answer. Can you check, whether simply the plural change is enough? Do you use `has_many` or `has_one` shop?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. user data is saved, but no shop record created. -- I use `has_many` shops

Comment: Try `f.fields_for :shops`. Watch for all these plural things!

Comment: Yes :-) That did the trick!! Thanks a lot! I spend hours on this ;-)

Comment: Ok, your welcome! I'll edit my answer so that you can accept it. Sometimes these tiny details can drive you mad :-)